# Model gets stuck at an almost static error

Tags: mnist

I am trying to solve MNIST. If I limit the training samples to just 0 and 1 everything works flawlessly. With the whole training model it gets stuck at a certain loss and all the predictions are just zeroes. My network structure is a convolutional layer with 32 5x5 filters and two fully connected layers from 32x24x24 to 100 to 10. Weights are initialized in a uniform distribution between -0.5 to 0.5. I train with mini-batch GD, 30 batch size, 20 epochs, 0.005 learning rate. Any help?

Comment: What is you loss function and last activation in the network?

Comment: Loss is MSE and last activation is a Sigmoid. I suspect the reason of these results would be a vanishing gradient, as it is a large network and using leakyReLU causes an exploding gradient, but I need confirmation, I am still learning.

Comment: You're trying to classify the digits, right? If so, you should use `categorical_crossentropy` (or `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` if not doing one-hot encoding of labels) as loss function, and `softmax` as the final activation. The rest seems fine. If this changes would solve your issue I can provide a more detailed answer, just let me know how it goes

Comment: Thank you, I did some research on my own and learned a lot, indeed those were issues, and now I also understand why (not going in depth, softmax gives me a probability distribution, and MSE is  not fit for classifiers). Thank you for confirming, I am currently working on implementing softmax and cross entropy as I am using a self-made ML framework.